# Как можно отключить пагинацию у дочерних категорий в Woocommerce?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Есть категория `milk_products`, в подкатегориях которой пытаюсь отключить пагинацию:

```
function disable_pagi_milk_products( $query ) {
    
    $current_cat = get_queried_object();
    $parent_cat = get_term( $current_cat->category_parent, 'category' );
    
    if ($parent_cat->slug == "milk_products") {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', -1 );
    }
    
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'disable_pagi_milk_products' )
```

Не отключается.